# tcp flood attack not works with hping3

Tags: apache, denial-of-service, hping

i want to do a dos attack to a website in my virtual machine. i use hping3 for that .

```
sudo hping3 -i u1 -S  -c 9999999999 192.168.58.3
```

in this ip address i have an apache server and a DVWA. when i input this ip address to the browser i see two folder : DVWA and html . when i choose DVWA i see the website. 
my problem is than althogh i use hping3 for attack and i want the website get down but the website not down and when i ping this ip address ttls are like when attack not occured. i search a lot and do all works i think . i don't know what is the problem. please help me. thanks

Comment: please help. i need help but you get me negative score !!!!!!!!!!! why?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$ sudo hping3 -i u1 -S -p 80 192.168.58.3

S - indicates SYN flag
p 80 - Target port 80
i u1 - Wait for 1 micro second between each packet
```

This would send TCP SYN packets to 192.168.58.3.